# RBS error and unable to upload documents more than 1.5 MB to a database configured with always on/

Tags: 2010, sql-server-2012, rbs, disaster-recovery

We are unable to upload a document more than 1.5 MB to a SharePoint content database which is configured RBS storage, and SharePoint data source instance is configured with SQL Server always on and this db in AG group.

In the WFE servers I was below RBS errors

```
Message ID:6, Level:ERR , Process:4496, Thread:11
Exception thrown:
Operation: StoreNewBlobFromStream1
BlobStoreId: 0
Log Time: 9/24/2016 9:48:00 AM
Exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.RemoteBlobStoreException: The blob store <FilestreamProvider_1> threw an exception. The exception thrown is saved in InnerException. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network name cannot be found
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream.OpenSqlFileStream(String path, Byte[] transactionContext, FileAccess access, FileOptions options, Int64 allocationSize)
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream..ctor(String path, Byte[] transactionContext, FileAccess access, FileOptions options, Int64 allocationSize)
   at Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.FilestreamBlobStore.FilestreamWriterStream.ExecuteStoreBlobProcedure(Boolean storeInBand)
   at Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.FilestreamBlobStore.FilestreamWriterStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.Utilities.ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
   at Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.FilestreamBlobStore.FilestreamStoreLibraryBase.CreateNewBlobFromStream(Byte[] storePoolId, Stream inStream)
   at Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.BlobStore.CreateNewBlobFromStream1Internal(Request request)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
ExceptionType:      BlobStore
ExceptionCode:      BlobStoreUnhandledException
Request Information:
Operation:          StoreNewBlobFromStream1
Request:
Request 13 for WriteBlobFromStream
Request Configuration not set.
Command Details:
StoreBlobCommand    : Request 13  , CheckedConfigVersion: Verified, RetryNeeded: False, RetryAttempts: 3
BlobDetails: BlobStoreId 1, PoolId 1, StorePoolId 0x01000000, CollectionId 2
ConfigItemList with 1 items.
Key: <blob_store_name>, Value:<FilestreamProvider_1>, ConfigFormat: <Name>, Required Level: <Application>
Session Information not set.
Provider Session Information:
Provider Session Info:
ProviderSession:         ProviderSession. Id: <1>, Name: <FilestreamProvider_1>, Type: <Filestream>, StoreVersion: <1.0.0.0>, Location: <Data Source=SQLPSPMC\xxx;Initial Catalog=Wss_content_88;Integrated Security=True;Application Name="Remote Blob Storage FILESTREAM Provider">
Core Configuration:
Extended Configuration:
```

[image]

I traced the correlation ID and found the errors

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The URL
>   'Documents/test2.pdf' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file
>   or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the
>   current Web.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.PutFile(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object punkFile, Int32 cbFile,
>   Object punkFFM, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String
>   bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object
>   varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties,
>   String bstrCheckinComment, Byte partitionToCheck, Int64
>   fragmentIdToCheck, String bstrCsvPartitionsToDelete, String
>   bstrLockIdMatch, String bstEtagToMatch, Int32 lockType, String lockId,
>   Int32 minutes, Int32 fRefreshLock, Int32 bValidateReqFields, Guid
>   gNewDocId, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage,
>   String& pEtagReturn, Byte& piLevel, Int32& pbIgnoredReqProps)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String
>   bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object punkFile, Int32 cbFile, Object punkFFM,
>   PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String bstrModifiedBy,
>   Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object varTimeCreated, Object
>   varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties, String bstrCheckinComment,
>   Byte partitionToCheck, Int64 fragmentIdToCheck, String
>   bstrCsvPartitionsToDelete, String bstrLockIdMatch, String
>   bstEtagToMatch, Int32 lockType, String lockId, Int32 minutes, Int32
>   fRefreshLock, Int32 bValidateReqFields, Guid gNewDocId, UInt32&
>   pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage, String& pEtagReturn,
>   Byte& piLevel, Int32& pbIgnoredReqProps)
>
> Application error when access /_layouts/UploadEx.aspx, Error=The URL
>   'Documents/test2.pdf' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file
>   or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the
>   current Web.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.PutFile(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object punkFile, Int32 cbFile,
>   Object punkFFM, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String
>   bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object
>   varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties,
>   String bstrCheckinComment, Byte partitionToCheck, Int64
>   fragmentIdToCheck, String bstrCsvPartitionsToDelete, String
>   bstrLockIdMatch, String bstEtagToMatch, Int32 lockType, String lockId,
>   Int32 minutes, Int32 fRefreshLock, Int32 bValidateReqFields, Guid
>   gNewDocId, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage,
>   String& pEtagReturn, Byte& piLevel, Int32& pbIgnoredReqProps)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String
>   bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object punkFile, Int32 cbFile, Object punkFFM,
>   PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String bstrModifiedBy,
>   Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object varTimeCreated, Object
>   varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties, String bstrCheckinComment,
>   Byte partitionToCheck, Int64 fragmentIdToCheck, String
>   bstrCsvPartitionsToDelete, String bstrLockIdMatch, String
>   bstEtagToMatch, Int32 lockType, String lockId, Int32 minutes, Int32
>   fRefreshLock, Int32 bValidateReqFields, Guid gNewDocId, UInt32&
>   pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage, String& pEtagReturn,
>   Byte& piLevel, Int32& pbIgnoredReqProps)

Comment: I got this issue before but without RBS , Check database size ,  drivers size and make sure there's available space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points have to check

- Try to merge the log file at WFE's to trace the correlation ID and specify what's specifically the root cause of this issue.
- Make sure SharePoint Database is not full.
- Check the Database hard drive has free space.
- Try to check the [filestream configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923(v=sql.105).aspx) on the SQL Server side.
- Reset IIS.

For more details [Sharepoint 2010 RBS can't add file larger than 1mb, The network name cannot be found](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4936521d-f12e-458e-8385-1e916349c84c/sharepoint-2010-rbs-cant-add-file-larger-than-1mb-the-network-name-cannot-be-found?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

Comment: hi what is the use of Windows share name in filestream tab in sql server for the perspective of storing files in rbs folder in sql server?

Comment: when i change to minimum blob storage settings to 5 MB and try to upload documents more than 50 MB throwing above error and <50 MB files not saved into RBS storage but saved in content db itself

Comment: If you want to read and write FILESTREAM data from Windows, click Enable FILESTREAM for file I/O streaming access. Enter the name of the Windows share in the Windows Share Name box.

Comment: Also check how to set Minimum BLOB Storage Size correctly http://www.reality-tech.com/setting-the-minimum-blob-storage-size-correctly/

Comment: also this link may be useful for you to review your setting for RBS with Always on https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2013/05/23/deploying-remote-blob-storage-with-sql-server-2012-alwayson-availability-groups/